# Extra Paging Section at the Top of Kendo UI Grid using Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui

I'm relatively new to Kendo so I'm hoping I'm using the right terminology and my apologies if this is confusing.  I've created a kendo ui grid in Razor and it would appear that my paging is creating a paging section correctly at the bottom of the grid and a second more default paging section at the top of the grid.  I have a png image but not sure how to load it so here's a description.  At the bottom of the grid, the paging is displayed correctly.  There are next and previous arrows, numeric buttons 1-3 on the bottom left and the correct messaging on the bottom right displaying "Showing items from 1 to 10. Total Items 30.

At the top of the grid, there is another paging section showing next and previous arrows on the top left with 1 numeric button and on the top right a message displaying "No items to display."

Here is the code for the Kendo grid:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<myModels.Models.QuotesSearchViewModel>()
            .Name("quotesGrid")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(c => c.AccountNumber);
                columns.Bound(c => c.QuoteNumber);
                columns.Bound(c => c.CustomerName);
                columns.Bound(c => c.TimeIn).Format("{0:hh:mm:ss tt}");
                columns.Bound(c => c.DateIn).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}");
                columns.Bound(c => c.QuoteNumber).ClientTemplate(
                    Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = "#= QuoteNumber #" }, new { @class = "k-button" }).ToHtmlString()
               );
            })
            .Selectable(selectable => selectable
                    .Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single))
            .Sortable()
            .Pageable(pageable => pageable
                .Messages(messages => messages.Display("Showing items from {0} to {1}. Total items: {2}"))
                .ButtonCount(5))
            .Navigatable()
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()
                .PageSize(10)
                .Model(model => model.Id("QuoteNumber"))
                .Read(read => read.Action("Quotes_Read", "Quotes").Data("filters"))
                )
    )
```

I have no problem populating the grid, selection works fine, everything is functioning properly with the exception of an extra paging section at the very top of the grid.  I'm not creating a kendo grid anywhere else on this page and I'm stumped about how this is getting there.  Has anyone else come across this?  Let me know if you need any further information.

Thank you for your time-Shaun

Comment: Could you be creating another grid using the JavaScript methods client side? This additional paging isn't something I've come across before, nor am I aware header paging is supported. The differing counts and messages strongly suggests two different grids.

Comment: Incidentally you'll be able to add images to questions once you reach ten reputation on StackOverflow, or over two hundred on any other StackExchange site (which then gives you one hundred reputation on all StackExchange sites).

Comment: Hello pwdst, thanks for the reply and the info about adding images.  That is the only grid, in fact it's pretty much the only code on the page.  I discovered what the problem was.  I had this code inside <div></div> tags.  I removed these tags and that paging section at the top of the grid went away.